# How to initiate a javascript function only after you've come from a certain URL?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have a page where a user enters values which is stored in localstorage. If the user clicks on save then the page redirects to a different page with the content appended to a table.

Or am I making this too complicated for myself? The reason I don't want to use the same function on the other page is to avoid the content to be continuously appended when you do a refresh. Also the save button is the only trigger for adding the content on another page.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve, what have you tried and what problems are you having?

Comment: GET parameter. LocalStorage flag. POST request submit. document.referrer.

Comment: Why would the content be continuously appended when you click refresh in the first place? Fix that, if it's indeed the case, and your problem is solved.

Comment: @DavidB

1) I want to take the content from one page and transfer/append to a table that is on a different html (Trigger is a button click event on the initial page)
2) I have tried taking the stored value in local storage and adding it on the first page however whenever I refresh my page, the content keeps getting appended.
3) I need a clean way to add content from one page to another with a button click event. When I refresh the page, the content should not be added again in a loop which is where I am stuck.

Comment: @ChrisG it was because I was initially loading content on the second page without any connection to the button click. I am having trouble trying to understand how to trigger a button click event on another page to change content on an another page

Comment: @jsnoobie You need to separate the logic of the two pages. One page appends data, the other displays it. If you find your code keeps appending data to localStorage, you need to make sure it doesn't by fixing the code that appends.

Comment: @ChrisG how would I go about targeting elements which are on another page and append the data to that then? I can target a p element in the same page and display the data in there with no problem but cannot with the same id on a different page :(

Comment: @jsnoobie No you can't, which is why I just told you to a) store the application state in localStorage and b) use pages to change or display it. If you want to append data to a `<p>` on another page, you need to a) append the data to a `localStorage` object, b) on the other page, load that data and display it in `<p>`.

Comment: @jsnoobie Also, no offense, but looking at your other questions it seems you have all the building blocks you need but simply lack experience when it comes to properly using them. This means it's too early to post on SO, especially multiple questions about essentially the same problem in a short time.

Comment: Well as my username suggests I am new to JS so I've been using SO as my go to to help me understand and learn this language better.

Comment: @jsnoobie That's not how SO works. It's not a free tutoring service. If you have just started out learning JS, it is WAY too early to post your problems here.

Answer (score 0):

try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange this approach to initiate a function when the url has been changed.